# Polylang on Wordpress site built with Timber won't switch author bios

Tags: wordpress, timber, polylang

I have a Wordpress site built on Timber/twig that uses Polylang to show different posts based on the language.

The posts show fine in the different languages, but the author bios that are loaded with:

```
{{ author.description }}
```

or

```
{{ post.author.description }}
```

only show the default language bio even when other language bios are entered into that author/user page.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

The Polylang documentation says nothing about how to properly add in a bio other than literally saying to enter the different bios into the user page....

Answer (score 0):

```
post.author.meta('description')
```